# SugarCrm pass data from controller to view

Tags: variable-assignment, sugarcrm

Good Morning,
I want to know if there's a magical way to pass variable created in the controllerModule to the ViewModule.
exemple:

```
$this->assign['result'] => $resultValue;
```

and in the view display()

```
echo $this->request['result'];
```

Maybe there's a better way to exchange data between Controller and View?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 7):

The `view_object_map` var is made for you.

In your controller you could do:

```
$this->view_object_map['myDataKey'] = 'MyData';
```

And you could retrieve your data easyly like that:

```
$this->ss->assign('myData', $this->view_object_map['myDataKey']);
```

or

```
echo $this->view_object_map['myDataKey'];
```